# Handlbars and HTML

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a database entry with the following data:

```
"text": "Paragraph 1\n\nParagraph 2\n\nParagraph 3\n"
```

However when I render this in `handlebars` as follows:

```
<div>{{{text}}}</div>
```

I get:

```
Paragraph 1 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 3
```

But I am expecting:

```
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2
Paragraph 3
```

Is anyone able to help explain what is going on?

Comment: Browsers remove newline characters while rendering. Use `<br>` instead

Comment: `\n` is not html. You need <br>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `\n` with `<br>` like this:

```
text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML elements do not preserve the line breaks, you need to use `<br>` instead, however you can use `<pre>`

The HTML `<pre>` element defines preformatted text. It preserves both spaces and line breaks.

additionally, since you are using handlebars, you can define a helper:

JS:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('breaklines', function(text) {
    text = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '<br>');
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(text);
});
```

HTML template:

```
<div>
    {{breaklines text}}
</div>
```

Comment: who ever -1'd my answer i need to know why.